# $dom(R\circ S) \subseteq domS$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

During the lesson we learned when doing composition of functions, it is true:

$$dom(R\circ S) \subseteq domS$$

Why this equality does not true?
$$dom(R\circ S) = domS$$

I think it always true, because we always going from the domain of S.
Why is it wrong?

Comment: Because some values of $S(x)$ for some $x\in \mathrm{dom\ }S$ may lie outside the domain of $R$?

Comment: are you working with totally defined functions or partially defined functions?

Comment: the distinction is totally or partially...

Comment: @user251257 Totally

Comment: then both domains are equal, otherwise $R\circ S$ isn't well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when you start from the domain of $S$, it could be possible that $S(x)$ is not in the domain of $R$, so it is impossible to calculate $(R\circ S)(x)$, and if this happen then $x\not\in dom(R\circ S)$

For instance, consider the real-valued functions $R(x)=\sqrt{x}$ and $S(x)=x$. Notice that $dom(S)=\mathbb{R}$, $(R\circ S)(x)=R(S(x))=\sqrt{S(x)}=\sqrt{x}$, whose domain is $dom(R\circ S)=[0,\infty)\subsetneq dom(S)$

Comment: Personally, I think this is just horrible convention. Surely, natural domain of $S$ is $\mathbb R$ but functions $(S, \mathbb R, \mathbb R)$ and $(S,\mathbb R_{\geq 0}, \mathbb R)$ are simply different functions. One is composable with $\sqrt{\ }$ and the other is not.